# Inspect module issues in pyinstaller frozen app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, inspect

I have written a file `pwrapper.py` which imports another package that I have written `packageapi`. packageapi uses inspect module in the following instruction

```
print (inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1])
```

I have frozen pwrapper.py using pyinstaller.

When I launch `pwrapper.exe` from command line, everything works fine. I get the output

```
<frame object at 0x01234567> pwrapper.py 19 new_table ['    packageapi.function()'] 0
```

However, when I launch `pwrapper.exe` by double clicking it, I get the following output

```
<frame object at 0x01234567> pwrapper.py 19 new_table None None
```

Why doesn’t the frame contain the lines and index when control is passed from pwrapper to packageapi.function when I double click on the exe?? I find it very weird that it behaves well when I run the exe from command line. Obviously there is something I don’t understand. Can someone help me fix it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. It turns out that I have to copy all the source code in the same directory structure but into the builds folder and it works fine now. I was hoping pyinstaller would do it, if that was mandatory!

Answer (score 0):

Running pyinstaller with a prebuilt .spec file with a few added lines can copy over your source code automatically when building the exe.

**No .spec file?**
*Running your .py file through pyinstaller will create a .spec file automatically.*
*If don't want to process everything and just to make the .spec file, run this-*

```
pyi-makespec pwrapper.py
```

---

Then modify your .spec file similar to this *(Windows example)*-

```
addedFiles = {
            ('README.md','.'),
            ('folder\\specific.file','folder\\.'),
            ('folder2\\subFolder\\*.ext','folder2\\subFolder\\.'),
            ('fullFolder\\*','fullFolder\\.'),
            }
a = Analysis([...]
             datas=addedFiles ,
             [...])
```

Then to run pyinstaller, point it to your .spec file instead of your .py file

```
pyinstaller pwrapper.spec
```

You can see an example where I'm using this method here-
[pxlViewer.spec](https://github.com/ProcStack/pxlViewer/blob/master/pxlViewer.spec)